# Import less file styling as a function for React frontend causiing curl command issues in Docker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker

I have a React app that uses less files for styling, but imports them in the following manner:

`import { b() } from 'awesomeStyles.less`;`

And then it uses it in a className like so:

`<div className={b()}></div>`

I have never seen anything like this.

Recently I built a Docker image, ran the frontend React project but when I try to curl an endpoint I get an error like this:

> react-i18next:: i18n.languages were undefined or empty undefined
> TypeError: (0, Page.b) is not a function

I got a similar error elsewhere in the application where it said:

`TypeError: (0, Spinner.b) is not a function`

I have no idea what's going on and I tried various troubleshooting steps. I ended up ripping out the whole `b()` import and className usage for Spinner, but now it's happening for the Page component and I suspect will keep happening for everywhere in the app that uses that `b()` as a way to import and use LESS files.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax import { b() } from 'awesomeStyles.less'; is not standard ES6 module syntax. Typically, when importing styles from LESS files in a React application, you wouldn't import specific functions like b(). Instead, you would import the entire styles object or specific classes directly.

```
import styles from 'awesomeStyles.less';
```

Comment: I absolutely agree.

Comment: I did not do this work, I am working with what I was given. I am open to an answer that also includes how to remove this nonsense and get it to standard ES6 module syntax.